# Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, webclient

Getting the error:
"Error occurred while calling Ariva's asset events api: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\n at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Request DTO:

```
public class DerivativeSearchRequest {
    private boolean groupBySearchTypeLevel;
    private int limit;
    private int offset;
    private String searchTypeLevel;
    private String sortLang;
    private String sortOrder;
    private String sortType;
    private List<Object> typeLevel0Ids;
    private List<Object> typeLevel1Ids;
    private List<Integer> typeLevel2Ids;
    private String underlyingId;
}
```

ClientImpl

```
this.webClient.post()
                .uri(derivativeURL)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyValue(derivativeSearchRequest)
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Object[].class)
                .block();
```

controllerImpl:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/derivative-search", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Operation(summary = "Get asset derivatives", description = "Request Body DTO for asset derivatives")
public ResponseEntity<Object[]> getDerivatives(@RequestBody DerivativeSearchRequest derivativeSearchRequest) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Request received to get asset derivatives for platform: {}",
            derivativeSearchRequest);
    final Object[] derivativesResponse = derivativeSearchService.getDerivatives(derivativeSearchRequest);
    System.out.println(derivativesResponse.toString());
    LOGGER.info("The asset derivatives details successfully retrieved");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(derivativesResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Can somebody help me over this. why getting this error.

Comment: Please add the JSON you are trying to deserialize.